# Get a text box value from a cell

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have created a table using PHP.

```
 echo "<td class=\"normalfnt\"  width=\"10\"  style=\"text-align:left; padding-left:9px;\" id=\"weightType\"/>$Description</td>";
             echo "<td class=\"normalfnt\" width=\"30\" > <input type=\"text\" size=\"6px\" id=\"fuelCost\" name=\"fc\"/></td>";
```

now i want to get the  the textbox value of the fuelcost. 
for that i tried to use following bellow javascript function

```
 function GetCellValues() {
  // alert('hi');
    var table = document.getElementById('tbl');

    //row.cells[index].getElementsByName('inputcell' + index)[0].value

    for (var r = 1, n = table.rows.length; r < n; r++) {
        for (var c = 0, m = table.rows[r].cells.length; c < m; c++) {
           alert(table.rows[r].cells[c].innerHTML);
        }
    }
}
```

now the problem im facing is that it won't give me the correct out put . but the html text box code i have put in the php code table ..
i would be very thankful if someone could help me with this.

Comment: You can simplify you code like `echo'<td class="normalfnt" width="10" style="text-align:left; padding-left:9px;" id="weightType">$Description</td><td class="normalfnt" width="30"><input type="text" size="6px" id="fuelCost" name="fc"/></td>';` ;)

Comment: Are the text inputs in a form? You can just do `yourFormElement.fc` to get the input named "fc."

Answer (score 2):

Since you have tagged with jQuery, try this solution

```
function GetCellValues() {
    //find all input elements with name fc within element with id table
    $('#tbl input[name="fc"]').each(function(){
        console.log($(this).val())
    });
}
```

Comment: `$('#tbl').find('input[name="fc"]')` is more optimized ?

Comment: Thanks for your kind help. but it didn work. just return nothing .

Comment: Did you wrap the script with `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });` or `$(function() { ... });` also did you include [jQuery](http://jquery.com/download/ "Download jQuery") library ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var values = $('#tbl').find('td > input[type="text"]').map(function(v){
    return v.value;
}).get();
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind help. but it didn work. just return nothing

Answer (score 0):

how about this,

```
function check()
{
    var table = document.getElementById("tbl");
    for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
       for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
            if(col.firstChild.nodeName=="INPUT")
            {
                console.log(col.firstChild.value);
            }
       }  
    }
}
```